# accordion with expandable sections

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create an accordion box with Javascipt and CSS. The expanded section should include a link that, when clicked, would enable this section already expanded to expand even more **without any vertical scroll bar**. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: are you using any specific framework? the answer is yes you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/2PSME/

You'll essentially want to take your existing accordion, and place 2 divs in the content area you want expanded. One will hold additional information (initially hidden) and the other will say "Click here for more". When you click that div, it disappears and causes the more info div to show. If you do this with a sliding animation, you will get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. The get the thing done quicker there are a lot of resources available for you out there.

Have a look at http://jquery.com/ and look at the demos of flowplayer, they are actually pretty impressive : http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion.html

Comment: I would like to have sections of the accordion that can be expanded more than its original expandable area, without the need of scrollbars...